# Writing SQL Query statement to get a specific user from table

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

I am using SQL query to get a specific user from the table, however, I am running into the issue where the postgresql is telling me that the column does not exist. It is a simple query statement that looks like this:

```
SELECT username FROM userlogins WHERE username = "test@email.com";

The ERROR:  column "test@email.com" does not exist
```

Comment: have you tried to visit any tutorial for postgresql fundamentals?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you use single quotes to delimit strings.  You use double quotes to escape identifiers.  You simply want:

```
SELECT username
FROM userlogins
WHERE username = 'test@email.com';
```

Some databases allow the use of double quotes for strings, but that is generally just confusing -- and Postgres is not one of those databases.

Comment: Thank you! This whole time, single quote was not something I though about. Thank you!